# Need a way of continuously looping/iterating around a Map

Tags: java, loops, continuous

I am building a game in java and I have a 'Map' of Player objects. I have a method called endOfTurn which is called when the player wants to finish their turn, It sets the 'currentPlayerTurn' field to the next player in the Map. However once I reach the end of my map i want it to go back to the first player in the map and go round again and again. Is there a way of doing this? Also yes the players data structure does need to be a map!

```
public class Game {

private Map<String,Player> players;
private Player currentPlayerTurn;

public boolean EndOfTurn(Player currentPlayerTurn) {
    //need to set this.currentPlayerTurn to the next player in the Map

}
```

I have looked into using an iterator but this doesnt seem to have a reset function or a 'loop around' mode. Any ideas?

Comment: You need a Circular LinkedList.

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` could do the job, it keeps the order how you entered the Players.

Comment: Circular linkedlist would work but i need it to be a map.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would have an outer loop which iterates over the players which calls this method.

```
while(playingGame) {
   for(Player player: players.values()) {
      player.takeTurn();
      endOfTurn(player);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your simplest option is:

```
while (!done) {
   // iterate once around your list
}
```

If your players need to be held in a `Map` then I wouldn't complicate matters by introducing new structures.

What you may want to consider is what happens if a player gets another turn (*can this happen?*). If so, an iterator isn't going to be a natural fit and perhaps you want some sort of `TurnManager` object that selects the next player to go. I wouldn't try to tie the game's behaviour to the data structure holding the players but rather abstract it out into a component that explicitly knows how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new Iterator from the Map. I mean, the way of "resetting" an Iterator is creating a new one.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Player>> it = players.entrySet().iterator();

//...

if(!it.hasNext())
    it=players.entrySet().iterator()
```

Let me try...

```
public class Game {

    private Map<String,Player> players;
    private Player currentPlayerTurn;
    private Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Player>> itPlayers;

    public boolean EndOfTurn(Player currentPlayerTurn) {
         if(itPlayers == null || !itPlayers.hasNext()){
           itPlayers=players.entrySet().iterator();   
         }
         currentPlayerTurn=itPlayers.next().getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand he's tried this but it doesn't have the loop-around behaviour he wants

Comment: He wrote: 'I have looked into using an iterator but this doesnt seem to have a reset of a 'loop around' mode'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a structure similar to a linked list node . endOfTurn() returns true if a round is finished else it returns false.

```
   Player {
    String name;
    boolean dealer;
    Payer nextPlayer;

    // constructor, getters and setters for fields

    }

    public class Game {

    private Map<String,Player> players;
    private Player currentPlayerTurn;

    public boolean endOfTurn(Player currentPlayerTurn) {
       currentPlayerTurn = currentPlayerTurn.getNextPlayer();

       if(currentPlayerTurn.isDealer())
          return true;
        else
          return false;
    }
```